# List all audio devices with Python's pyaudio (portaudio binding)

Tags: python, audio, portaudio, pyaudio

I tried

```
import pyaudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
    print p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
```

but I don't get the full list of all devices : for example I don't get ASIO devices in this list. This is strange, because `portaudio` should give ASIO devices as well, right ?

**How can I list all audio devices with `pyaudio` ?**

Comment: I tried your code, with a pyaudio binary from: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio for me it prints all my ASIO devices

Comment: Yes @EmileVrijdags, I contacted M. Gohlke a few months ago, and he updated his binaries with ASIO support.  (my original post was in Dec 2013)

Comment: cool! I'll make good use of it ;)

Answer (score 9):

I've created (a while after this question was posted) the [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.rtfd.org/) module for Python, which includes [its own DLLs](https://github.com/spatialaudio/portaudio-binaries) with ASIO support (and all other host APIs, too).
It can be installed with:

```
pip install sounddevice --user
```

After that, you can list all your devices with:

```
python -m sounddevice
```

Of course you can also do this within Python:

```
import sounddevice as sd
sd.query_devices()
```

Comment: python3.6 -m sounddevice (prints nothing)

Comment: @ChrisP Please create an issue as described in https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/CONTRIBUTING.html.

Answer (score 1):

I think your expectations are reasonable. The equivalent C code to enumerate PortAudio devices would give you all available devices. There are a couple of things that could be wrong:

- Your build of PyAudio has not been compiled with ASIO support. PortAudio will only enumerate devices for the native host APIs that have been configured/compiled in at compile time.
- You have a 64-bit build of Python/PyAudio and your ASIO device drivers are 32-bit, or vis-versa (64-bit ASIO drivers and 32-bit Python).

As Multimedia Mike suggests, you can eliminate PyAudio from the equation by enumerating PA devices from C. The pa_devs.c program in the PortAudio distribution does this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I spent hours and hours to try to compile PyAudio *with* ASIO support (thanks to the discussion https://github.com/bastibe/PyAudio/pull/4) but unfortunately I cannot finish the compile... If you have time to have a look at the procedure described here https://github.com/bastibe/PyAudio/pull/4 @RossBencina, thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2):

I'm thinking that the problem could be in the underlying PortAudio library. Do you have (or can you write, in C) a simple utility that accesses the PortAudio library and tries to perform this same listing?

Also, googling for 'portaudio asio' reveals [this tidbit from the official PortAudio docs](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/api_overview.html):

> There are cases where PortAudio is limited by the capabilities of the
>   underlying native audio API... the ASIO SDK only allows one device to
>   be open at a time, so PortAudio/ASIO doesn't currently support opening
>   multiple ASIO devices simultaneously.

Comment: I need to study this. I don't have a C compiler/linker installed (and those libraries neither) right now, and quite no knowledge about this... Would you have such tools @MultimediaMike ?

Comment: The fact that PortAudio can't open *streams* to multiple ASIO devices simultaneously has no bearing on enumerating device info.

Comment: The `sounddevice` module also uses PortAudio which *can* find the correct device.